# How do you force Windows 7 to release a mapped file?

Tags: windows-7, windows

After installing an application from an ISO file, for some reason Windows 7 still caches the file as mapped file, limiting my memory severely.

I've unloaded the ISO file and shut off the program that loads it. Needless to say, it did not work.

Is there a way to force the OS to release the memory for the mapped file?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you saying, that within Windows Explorer, right clicking on the mapped drive and selecting disconnect doesn't work, or that it has re-joined by next login?

Comment: @DaveRook It's a local drive. Can't disconnect it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the "Empty Standbylist" action under "Empty" to clear the Superfetch cache. But this doesn't impact you. if Windows needs RAM, it empties the Cache itself.

Comment: @magiccandre1981 This solved the issue. Thanks.

Comment: @l46kok btw, wj32 posted a CLI tool which does the same: http://forum.sysinternals.com/rammap-empty-standby-list_topic27297_post132769.html#132769 . So you can script it if needed.